# Why doesn't x_range_type 'datetime' work with just one glyph/data point?

Tags: bokeh

I am using 'datetime' as the x_axis_type parameter in my plot figure. It works perfectly when there are multiple glyphs on my plot.

[image: keh]

However, when I make another plot with only one glyph, the x ticker shows as (mili?) seconds rather than a datetime despite the x_axis_type remaining the same.

[image]

Surely there is a simple fix I don't know about?

Thank you in advance.

Full (ipynb) code:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
import pandas as pd

output_notebook()

df = pd.read_csv('my_data.csv')

df['Created'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Created'], utc=True)

plot = figure(x_axis_type='datetime')
plot.circle(df['Created'], df['Incident Duration MTTR Mins'])
show(plot)


# Second plot, this time only with one glyph
plot2 = figure(x_axis_type='datetime')
plot2.circle(df['Created'][0], df['Incident Duration MTTR Mins'][0])

show(plot2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've managed a solution:

```
from bokeh.models import DatetimeTickFormatter

...

plot2.xaxis.formatter=DatetimeTickFormatter(microseconds=["%Y-%m-%d"])
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the default range is an instance of `DataRange1d`, and if you don't have enough points for it to determine the span of the data, it will use the default value 2 (milliseconds, in this case).

Comment: A proper solution would be to just set the `default_span` attribute to some high value. Otherwise, you won't be able to see e.g. hours when you zoom in far enough.

Comment: Would suggest making a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) about this. There is never going to be a default span value (or even policy) that works perfectly well under all cases, but perhaps we can adjust the default span when a datetime axis is present.